# Extend Python unittest result object to hold a screenshot

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, python-unittest

I currently have a python selenium webdriver project where test results are saved to a database.
The results of the test runs are then displayed in a web page to allow easy viewing.

I'd like to improve this so that it is possible to view a screenshot of the failure as well.

I've been able to extend the addError and addFailure methods in unittest.TestCase to take a screenshot, but I can't work out how to extend the TestResult object to hold this screenshot.

My TestBaseClass currently looks like this, but throws a too many arguments error on addError.

```
class TestCaseBase(unittest.TestCase):

    def run(self, result=None):
        super(TestCaseBase, self).run(TestResultEx(result, self))


class TestResultEx(object):
    def __init__(self, result, testcase):
        self.result = result
        self.testcase = testcase

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return object.__getattribute__(self.result, item)

    def addError(self, test, error):
        screenshot = self.testcase.driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
        self.result.addError(test, error, screenshot)
```